# Non-numeric characters in number field producing errors

Tags: craft3, entry, field, number

Craft 3 is giving me this error when my client enters non-numeric characters into a number field on an entry:

> number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given

Is there a way for it to check and remove non-numeric characters from the field on save? Or maybe my setup is incorrect?

Comment: Is it an error or an exception? Because it actually should display errors rather than removing the characters. You could create a custom field that strips all letters from the input

Comment: Per an image my client sent: PHP Warning - yii\base\ErrorException

Comment: Shouldn't craft handle this natively? Either not allowing non-numeric characters in number fields or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested this on a local Craft3 setup and here's what I discovered...

If the `decimal points` setting on the number field is set to `0`, adding text in the number field will display the pretty errors below:

[image]

If the `decimal points` setting is set to anything else, you get the Twig error mentioned in the title of this post:

> number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given

I'd recommend opening an issue in the [Craft CMS repo](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc) as I imagine the number field ought to display the pretty errors no matter if `decimal points` is set or not.

Comment: Issue is here for anyone else reading this thread. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3416